# Convert B(C(),D()) to (c,d)=>B(()=>c(),()=>d()) - Generating delegate wrappers from MethodInfos?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, methods, delegates

Ultimately, I'm looking forward to a reflection based approach to create a delegate wrapper for a method B(C(),D()) - to some what like  (c,d)=>B(()=>c(),()=>d())

First question - Given that you've a Methodinfo, what are the considerations to create a delegate type (via reflection) which corresponds to that method signature?

Do you have a reference to the code chunk of any open source projects that does this? :P

**Update:** Here is a generic way to create a delegate for a methodinfo [Builds a Delegate from MethodInfo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124563/builds-a-delegate-from-methodinfo) - I think recursively wrapping the parameters part is something I've to work out over the weekend.

Comment: Glad that you are looking forward to it. Have a nice time. ;)

Comment: Just hanging around and looking for jonskeet :P

Comment: Why do you want to provide another layer of needless indirection?

Comment: Sounds like you're trying something Eric is currently explaining [in his blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/10/21/continuation-passing-style-revisited-part-one.aspx).

Comment: @leppie Why do you think it is needless? Should be useful for creating wrappers for Currying, Continuous passing style etc..

Comment: @Oliver, there you are, a dynamic wrapper for CPS on top of existing methods, of course inspired by this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/10/21/continuation-passing-style-revisited-part-one.aspx

Comment: **@leppie** bored smart people are *dangerous*.

Comment: Looks quite related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124563/builds-a-delegate-from-methodinfo

Comment: @amazedsaint: CPS is continuation passing style. Your code does not capture the continuation, so I dont see what is being tried here.

Comment: @amazedsaint: Also, if you dont use tail calls, CPS will blow up your stack. @Eric Lippert does not mention this very important point.

Comment: Sorry, I made the classic mistake, I meant `proper tail recursion` and not `tail calls` (the latter being an implementation detail).

Comment: @leppie My original question was just pointed at creating a delegate wrapper from a method info, CPS was not anywhere in the question. Mentioned CPS and currying to clarify why redirection is useful, not strictly wrt to the original question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `Expression` to build dynamic methods. Here is an example according to your question. I'm taking `Console.Write(string s)` as an example.

```
    MethodInfo method = typeof(Console).GetMethod("Write", new Type[] { typeof(string) });
    ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string),"str");
    MethodCallExpression methodExp = Expression.Call(method,parameter);
    LambdaExpression callExp = Expression.Lambda(methodExp, parameter);
    callExp.Compile().DynamicInvoke("hello world");
```

Comment: Nope. A better, generic approach is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124563/builds-a-delegate-from-methodinfo  - but that don't wrap the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to create a working delegate from the MethodInfo of a method like this:

Method and delegate:

```
public static int B(Func<int> c, Func<int> d) {
  return c() + d();
}

public delegate int TwoFunc(Func<int> c, Func<int> d);
```

Code:

```
MethodInfo m = typeof(Program).GetMethod("B");
TwoFunc d = Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(TwoFunc), m) as TwoFunc;
int x = d(() => 1, () => 2);
Console.WriteLine(x);
```

Output:

```
3
```

Not sure how useful it is, though...